# Safari does not animate when adding class to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this website: [Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/thebigsmileXD/pen/PzyANg) (You can see the code there. Animation starts when you click)

It works perfectly on every browser, even edge.
Except for Safari.

I've been fixing the keyframe animations where i only had "to {}" and added "from{}" to it, i even tried filling out the from to contain the same pieces like to

i added all -webkit- animations and this atleast fixed the background.

The thing is: i have an overlay div called "loading-cover", with the class .loading-cover

I later append a class using jquery `document.getElementById("loading-cover").classList.add('loaded');`

Every browser then starts the alternative animation, safari doesn't

Comment: What browsers did you try?

Comment: Don't link to an external website. Instead, create a reduced demonstration of the problem right here on stackoverflow. In the future someone might have the same issue and if the page got removed he won't be able to fix his problem.

Comment: can u post that css animation code

Comment: I tried Safari, edge, opera, chrome, firefox and IE10.

Answer (score 0):

I found this parsing error in Safari Console:

[image]

Comment: Thats interesting, doesn't happen on chrome.